# Update the original sentence using index and content of the added and deleted words

Tags: java, python, data-structures

I have this text, which has been annotated with index inside the parenthesises:

```
Michael(1) Wigglesworth,(2) like(3) Taylor(4) an(5) Englishborn(6),
Harvard-educated(7) Puritan(8) minister.(9)
```

And these information (content and index):

```
*Deleted : 
 Wigglesworth - 2
 like - 3
 Taylor - 4
 an - 5
 Englishborn, - 6

*Added:
Wigglesworth, - 2
is - 3
a - 4
handsome - 5
men - 6 
who - 7
is - 8
```

This will be the updated sentence:

```
Michael Wigglesworth is a handsome men who is Harvard-educated Puritan minister.
```

I was thinking about using a LinkedList.. Do you have any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Wigglesworth - 2` should be in "added" and `Wigglesworth, - 2` in "deleted."

Comment: What's the purpose of the index in the "deleted" list? If the word specified by the index isn't the same word, what should be the correct behavior? Does the input sentence comes with the `(index)`, or were you trying to make it easier for the readers to understand?

Comment: because it is not necessary that there are added words in place of deleted words

Comment: Please select one language only. It would also help to include your efforts. As of now, your question reads like you want others to do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be more easily done with list methods `pop` and `insert`. For deletion you have to delete from the higher index first, while for insertion you have to insert from the lower index first, to keep the target indexes accurate. Also indexes in Python have a base of 0 so you need to adjust your input indexes accordingly.

```
string = 'Michael Wigglesworth, like Taylor an Englishborn, Harvard-educated Puritan minister.'
delete = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
add = {
    1: 'Wigglesworth',
    2: 'is',
    3: 'a',
    4: 'handsome',
    5: 'men',
    6: 'who',
    7: 'is'
}
words = string.split()
for i in delete[::-1]:
    words.pop(i)
for i, word in add.items():
    words.insert(i, word)
print(' '.join(words))
```

This outputs:

```
Michael Wigglesworth is a handsome men who is Harvard-educated Puritan minister.
```